# How can I kill completely a process while using CreateNoWindow = true

Tags: c#

I have a problem that I can't terminate a running process
when I set `UseShellExcute = false` and `CreateNoWindow = true`.

Here is the code:

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
Boolean TimeLimit = process.WaitForExit(2000);
if (TimeLimit == false)
{
    process.Kill();
    return "Time Limit Exceeded";
}
```

After the program exit, the process is still running (checked in Task Manager)
If I set `CreateNoWindow = false` and use `closeMainWindow` like this:

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
Boolean TimeLimit = process.WaitForExit(2000);
if (TimeLimit == false)
{
    process.CloseMainWindow();
    return "Time Limit Exceed";
}
```

it works fine.
But I don't want it to show the window while running.

is there any other way to do this? I need some help

Comment: What is the command you are running, `"cmd.exe"` ?

Comment: yes it is , i'm using "cmd.exe" to excute java files.

Comment: The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited. From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Killing cmd.exe will not kill java.exe.  Just don't use cmd.exe, run java.exe directly.

Comment: @HansPassant answer it up and get some easy points